# How to improve miou for deeplabV3+ ?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, semantic-segmentation

Currently I’m struggling with improving the results on semantic segmentation problem using *deeplabV3+* trained on my own dataset.
I’ve trained *deeplabV3+* successfully a few times using different pretrained models from the model zoo, all based on *xception_65*, but my results keep staying in the same **miou** range, somewhere around this interval **[10, 11]**.
I have only one GPU at my disposal with 11GB GPU memory.
My dataset has **8 classes** with various object sizes, from little to big, and is quite unbalanced.
Here are the label weights: [1, 4, 4, 17, 42, 36, 19, 20].
In my dataset I have **757** instances for **training** and **100** **validation**.

When training the general tendency is: the first 10k iterations my loss decreases, but then it only oscillates.
I’ve tried:

- to adjust parameters like: the learning rate, last_layer_gradient_multiplier, weight decay
- training on various image sizes **321, 513, 769**
- some kind of weighting using the above weights in this formula

  weights = tf.to_float(tf.equal(scaled_labels, 0)) * 1 +
            tf.to_float(tf.equal(scaled_labels, 1)) * 4 +
            tf.to_float(tf.equal(scaled_labels, 2)) * 4 +
            tf.to_float(tf.equal(scaled_labels, 3)) * 17 +
            tf.to_float(tf.equal(scaled_labels, 4)) * 42 +
            tf.to_float(tf.equal(scaled_labels, 5)) * 36 +
            tf.to_float(tf.equal(scaled_labels, 6)) * 19 +
            tf.to_float(tf.equal(scaled_labels, 7)) * 20 +
            tf.to_float(tf.equal(scaled_labels, ignore_label)) * 0.0

I’ve trained without fine tuning the batch normalization parameters (***fine_tune_batch_norm = False***). Although I also tried training those parameters (***fine_tune_batch_norm = True***) with a 321 crop size in order to be able to fit a **batch size** of **12** in my GPU.

The point being I need some *tips* to figure out what I can do to *improve* those results.
What do you guys think? Do I need *more data* in order to increase my miou or *hardware*?